# Do any scriptures mention Lakshmi's 18 sons and Astha Lakshmi?

Tags: scripture, identification-request, avatars, lakshmi

I know Lakshmi has 18 sons and that she took eight forms called Astha Lakshmi.

Do any scriptures mention them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interestingly, no. **None of the Hindu scriptures explicitly mention the Ashta Lakshmi or the 18 sons.**

Adi Lakshmi, Dhana Lakshmi, Dhanya Lakshmi, Gaja Lakshmi, Santana Lakshmi, Dhairya Lakshmi, Vijaya Lakshmi, and Vidya Lakshmi are never mentioned as individuals or as collectives.

The next best thing to do is to look at the Ashtalakshmi stotra, which was composed in the 20th century. It was written by a rishi, so it has some spiritual weight, but it is rather contemporarily written. [Here](https://www.hinduismoutlook.com/ashtalakshmi-stotram-lyrics-meaning/) is a translation.

Perhaps it's worth noting that the [Padma Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-padma-purana/d/doc365813.html) *does* talk of 8 Lakshmis, but these Lakshmis are different from the ones mentioned above that are traditionally considered the Ashta Lakshmi:

> The eight powers—the eight bodies of Lakṣmī- Ramā, Rukmiṇī, Sītā, Padmā, Padmālayā, Śivā, Sulakṣaṇā and Suśīlā; they protect that place (lit. world) with weapons like conches, discs, maces, lotuses and śārṅgas (bows), and with lotus-like arrays formed around.

---

As for the sons, we have the names of four of them, but not the other fourteen.

Rig Veda, Sri Suktam:

> We are the progeny of our forefather, **Sage Kardama, who is one of the sons of Goddess Lakshmi.** We invoke that Sage Kardama to install in his family the Universal Mother, Mahalakshmi, who is decked with the garland of lotuses. So be it.
>
> We invoke another **son of Lakshmi named Chikleeta**. May he dwell in our home and may his mother, Mahalakshmi, dwell in our family.

[Brahmanda Purana](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-brahmanda-purana/d/doc343253.html):

> Śrī, purified the worlds. The splendid lady attained lord Nārāyaṇa as her husband. **Bala** (strength) and **Unmāda** (lunacy) were born of her as the sons of Nārāyaṇa.